# Hybrid Phonegap Build + Ember.js app is not loading

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ember.js, phonegap-build

I'm currently having a problem with an app made in Phonegap Build + Ember.js. When I test it with Ripple is everything OK. But when I upload my code to be compiled for the different platforms and download it with my Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.2), it seems Ember isn't loading any Route/Controller/View/Model/Template.

I don't know if the hybrid app needs to behave like an application server to load Ember features and isn't doing it. Can anyone help?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would recommend checking the logs of your Android app to see if the WebView is producing any helpful errors. You can use logcat for this.

Comment: how are your js files loaded? do you have them locally? if you are loading them from a different domain then you might have a security problem related to the application whitelist: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html, just guessing...

Comment: Is it possible you need to whitelist some of the foreign modules? Are you using a CDN to load jQuery? Refer to this: http://www.prosoxi.com/2011/10/08/xcode-phonegap-white-list-rejection/